# Do formulas use unary functions in first-order oodle theory?

Tags: set-theory, big-numbers

BIG FOOT is supposedly a finite number which is defined using first-order oodle theory (an extension of set-theory) like defined [here](https://googology.wikia.org/wiki/User_blog:LittlePeng9/First_order_oodle_theory). It has been shown [here](https://googology.wikia.org/wiki/BIG_FOOT) that BIG FOOT is not well-defined. The reasoning goes as the following:

> Suppose that the transfinite ordinal $\alpha_0$ in the original definition is formalised in $T$ by a defining formula $\varphi(\alpha)$ with a free occurence of a variable term $\alpha$. Then the existence of $\alpha_0$ satisfying $\varphi(\alpha_0)$ ensures that the existence of $\beta < \alpha_0$ satisfying $\varphi(\beta)$ by the definition of $\alpha_0$. By the minimality of $\alpha_0$, it implies $\alpha_0 = \beta < \alpha_0$, which contradicts the well-foundedness of $\alpha_0$.

I have a question: is $\varphi$ unary and why it is? I've thought that the language of first-order oodle theory uses n variables as an input.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is that "oodle theory" does not really exist yet, isn't it? Once an actual formal theory is provided, you have a reasonable definition.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't, but why do we want to disprove its existence using an unary function?

Comment: I don't know. What I'm saying is that you cannot really disprove anything yet, as there is no theory to work with. Once a (consistent) theory is specified, you will have a fine definition. Whether something is unary or not does not seem to matter at this point. In any case, the whole argument is difficult to follow as written since nothing is formal yet.